# How to set regional settings with ODBC connection string (in Access VBA)

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, odbc

In short: How do I edit this setting in an ODBC connection string?

[image]

I use the function below to add ODBC tables to an Access application, without the need of a stored ODBC connection (how to call this, ODBC DSN?) on the users machine.

But I now experience issues with a user which has different regional settings on his machine. The table is showing the data in the users regional settings, which causes issues in the forms.
When I add the same table to the same application, but via the manual way (so by selecting the ODBC driver/stored DSN), it is shown in the SQL format.

Below is a comparison of both tables. Left is the manual one, with correct format. Right is the table added via this code.

[image]

I already added:
;Regional=No

But it doesn't seem to have effect. I'm sure that the table is added by the code, it was dropped first and then added, I've checked all steps to see if it wasn't skipping something.

What am I missing here?

```
Function AttachDSNLessTable(stLocalTableName As String, stRemoteTableName As String, stServer As String, stDatabase As String, Optional stUsername As String, Optional stPassword As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo AttachDSNLessTable_Err
    Dim td As TableDef
    Dim stConnect As String
    
    For Each td In CurrentDb.TableDefs
        If td.Name = stLocalTableName Then
            CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete stLocalTableName
        End If
    Next
      
    stConnect = "ODBC;DRIVER=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server;SERVER=" & stServer & ";DATABASE=" & stDatabase & ";Trusted_Connection=Yes;Regional=No"

    Set td = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef(stLocalTableName, dbAttachSavePWD, stRemoteTableName, stConnect)
    CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append td
    
    AttachDSNLessTable = True
    Exit Function

AttachDSNLessTable_Err:

    AttachDSNLessTable = False

    
            
End Function
```